# bootstrap datepicker ... how to change options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and initiate him like this

```
        <input class="form-control datepicker" id="sel3">

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: " dd-mm-yyyy",
            startView: "days",
            minViewMode: "days"
        });
```

I have an input-field to input a date. But I want to be able to switch between "you can select the full date dd-mm-yyyy" and "you can only select the year yyyy". I already figured out that I can set the startView to year ... but I cannot change it to day to select the full date.

I tried this but I failed.

```
if(something){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: " dd-mm-yyyy",
            startView: "days",
            minViewMode: "days"
        });
 }else {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: " yyyy",
            startView: "years",
            minViewMode: "years"
        });
 }
```

Comment: can you explain it clear...

Comment: Is this your goal? http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/1333/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing startview to 'year' or change 'startView' itself to 'viewMode'